# how can i write latex code to produce this rectangle as picture

Tags: tables, diagrams

[image: how can i write the Latex code and to produce this rectangle as below?]

anyone can help me this question,i really hurry,

Comment: Such broad issues are not likely to get an answer. Please let this helpful audience know what you have tried, and then if you face any specific issues, people will extend their hands to render their cooperation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How can I add a soluton using PSTricks ?

Answer (score 1):

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] % <--- scale goes HERE!
    \begin{scope}[line width=2pt]
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} {
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,3} {
                \draw (\x*0.2,\y*0.2) rectangle +(0.2,0.2);
            }
        }
        \node[right] at (11*0.2,2*0.2) {2 squares};
        \node (a1) at (9*0.2+0.1,0*0.2) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[ultra thick,yshift=-1.2cm]
        \node (b1) at (2*0.2,3*0.2) {};
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,3} {
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,2} {
                \draw (\x*0.2,\y*0.2) rectangle +(0.2,0.2);
            }
        }
        \node[right] at (11*0.2,1*0.2+0.1) {1 square};
        \node (b2) at (3*0.2+0.1,0*0.2) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[thin,yshift=-2.0cm]
        \node (c1) at (1*0.2+0.1,1*0.2) {};
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,2} {
            \foreach \y in {0} {
                \draw (\x*0.2,\y*0.2) rectangle +(0.2,0.2);
            }
        }
        \node[right] at (11*0.2,0*0.2+0.1) {3 squares};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[help lines,-latex] (a1) -- +(0,-0.3) -| (b1);
    \draw[-latex] (b2) -- +(0,-0.3) -| (c1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: but my output the picture is so samll. how can i let it be bigger that same as you shown as above ?

Comment: Add `[scale=<factor>]` to the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: where is the tikzpicture environment? i try to add the \usepackage{tikz}[scale=<factor>],it is fair, can you show me directly? thx

Comment: See my updated answer. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user43336".

Comment: it is still the same...do you know how to let the grid line be the bold?

Comment: See my updated answer to compare different modifiers for linestyles. If my answer is helpful, you can show your appreciation by upvoting my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: I also suggest reading the (excessive) [`pgfmanual`](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf) before asking for every bit of configuration on TeX.SX. As a starting point, go through the tutorials in Part I: Tutorials and Guidelines on page 27.